# Show that the mapping which sends an element to its norm is open

Tags: general-topology

Consider the mapping $$\varphi: \mathbb{R}^n \to [0,\infty)\\
x \to \|x\|_2$$ I think it is true, that $\varphi$ is an open mapping. I tried to prove this by considering any open set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $A$ is open, we find for any $x \in A$ an open ball $B_{\varepsilon_x}(x)$ with radius $\varepsilon_x$ depending on $x$ such that $B_{\varepsilon_x}(x) \subseteq A$. Then we can write $$A = \bigcup_{x \in A} B_{\varepsilon_x}(x)$$ as a union of open sets. Now if we apply $\varphi$ we get $$\varphi(A) = \bigcup_{x \in A} \varphi\left(B_{\varepsilon_x}(x)\right)$$ Now I am not sure how to prove that $\varphi\left(B_{\varepsilon_x}(x)\right)$ is open in $[0,\infty)$. Any ideas? Or is there a better way?

**Edit.**  According to Julián Aguirre's post, here is the proof of the inclusion $$\varphi(B_\varepsilon(x))\supseteq(\|x\|-\varepsilon,\|x\|+\varepsilon).$$ Let $\left| \delta \right| < \varepsilon/\left\| x\right\|$. Then $$\left\| (1 + \delta)x - x\right\| = \left| \delta\right|\left\| x\right\| < \frac{\varepsilon}{\left\| x\right\|}\left\| x\right\| = \varepsilon$$ and thus $(1 + \delta)x \in B_\varepsilon(x)$. Further $$\left\| (1 + \delta)x\right\| = \left| 1 + \delta\right| \left\| x\right\| \leq \left( 1 + \left| \delta\right| \right)\left\| x\right\| < \left( 1 + \frac{\varepsilon}{\left\| x\right\|} \right)\left\| x\right\| = \left\| x \right\| + \varepsilon$$ and by $\varepsilon/\left\| x \right\| < 1$ $$\left\| (1 + \delta)x\right\| = \left| 1 - \left(- \delta\right)\right| \left\| x\right\| \geq \left| 1 - \left| \delta\right| \right|\left\| x\right\| > \left( 1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{\left\| x\right\|} \right)\left\| x\right\| = \left\| x \right\| - \varepsilon$$ Since there exists a bijection between $\left( -\varepsilon/\left\| x\right\|, \varepsilon/\left\| x\right\|\right)$ and $\left( \left\| x\right\| - \varepsilon, \left\| x\right\| + \varepsilon\right)$ we are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $0<r<\|x\|$. If $y\in B_r(x)$ then
$$
\|y\|=\|y-x+x\|\le\|y-x\|+\|x\|<\|x\|+r.
$$
Similarly
$$
\|y\|=\|y-x+x\|\ge\|x\|-\|y-x\|>\|x\|-r.
$$
Thus
$$
\varphi(B_r)\subset(\|x\|-r,\|x\|+r).
$$
I leave to you to show that we can change $\subset$ by $=$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. To show that equality holds it is enough to show the other inclusion. This results in showing, that for any element $y \in (\|x\|- r,\|x\| + r)$ there exists an element $z \in B_r(x)$ such that $\|z\| = y$. Am I on the right way?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Perhaps you could have a look at my edit and tell me if the proof is correct. Thank you so much.

Comment: Once again, all is OK.